# When are pdb files actually loaded

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

When doing a "Debug" Build in Visual Studio it outputs a pdb file so that you get detailed information when an exception occurs.

Is the information in the pdb files actually loaded when the executable is run or later at the moment when the exception occurs?

Comment: A lot of people build .pdb files for release builds too.

Answer (score 1):

Decompilers such as IDA load symbol files when it analyses your executable, or when you tell it to load specific symbols with your executable, as long as it matches the executable currently being debugged.

Debuggers such as the Visual Studio debugger load PDB files and symbols as soon as it starts debugging, not when an exception occurs.

[The MSDN page on PDB files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) further underlines this:

> The Visual Studio debugger uses the project.PDB file created by the
>   linker directly and embeds the absolute path to the PDB in the EXE or
>   DLL file. If the debugger cannot find the PDB file at that location or
>   if the path is invalid (for example, if the project was moved to
>   another computer), the debugger searches the path containing the EXE,
>   the Symbol Path specified in the solution's Property Pages (Common
>   Properties folder, Debug Symbol Files page). The debugger will not
>   load a PDB that does not match the binary being debugged.

Of course, is a program is compiled without **/debug**, the path to the PDB file won't be included in the resulting exe or DLL.

Comment: ok thanks, but are they loaded at the time an exception occurs or at time of application startup?

Comment: They are loaded at the time your application is being debugged; when the debugger starts debugging. JIT may do something with them if you are compiling as **/release** and an exception occurs, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are loaded outside of VS. If your code crashes while loaded with the PDB's you'll see source code location and line numbers.

Comment: ok, but are they loaded at the moment of the crash or at the startup of the application?

Comment: @clamp: Not even the executable is loaded at the startup of the application (!). It's done by paging in the code as page faults happen. As a result, unused code isn't paged in at all.